# Cross platform service discovery with consul

Tags: php, node.js, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I have developed simple micro service using String boot.

I register my service with [consul](https://www.consul.io/) using [spring cloud](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/).

Now my question is how another application is written in different language ie. node or PHP consume my service from consul.

Comment: This is a bit too broad for SO, you need to have a more specific issue that would be solvable by a particular piece of code rather than looking at how something is used.

Comment: Yes, correct. Here any code sample or any blog/article link will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Consul HTTP API](https://www.consul.io/api/index.html) to get lot of information from Consul (e.g. about registered services as well). To simplify the usage of it there are lot of clients and sdks listed [here](https://www.consul.io/api/libraries-and-sdks.html) (there are also libs for PHP). Also you can use [DNS Interface](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html) for discovery of registered services.